# How do I get the 7-Zip exit code from the console output?

Tags: c#, 7zip

I am writing a c# application that uses 7-zip to compress a directory.  7-Zip returns an exit status after zipping up a file.  In the console window all I see is

`Everything is Ok`

which equates to an exit code of 0.  But does anybody know if there is a way I can get that number?

Comment: Are you starting 7-zip as a separate process, or accessing the DLLs directly from C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're starting 7-zip as a separate process using the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx):

> *Process.ExitCode* Property
>
> Gets the value that the associated process specified when it terminated.

---

You might be interested in [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) which provides a managed wrapper for the 7z.dll.